# multiselect, set default selected values

Tags: zend-framework

How can I set selected values for a multiselect within my controller?
This is my code so far

```
    class Blog_Form_Post extends Zend_Form
    {
        public function init()
        {
    ...
            $this->addElement('multiselect', 'categories', array(
                'label'      => 'Categories:',
                'required'   => false,
            )); 
    ...

            $form = new Blog_Form_Post();
            $categories = new Blog_Model_DbTable_Categories();
            $categories = $categories->fetchAll();
            foreach ($categories as $category)
            {
// Some of the categories needs to selected by default
                $form->getElement('categories')->addMultiOption($category->ID, $category->name);


        }
```

Edit to be more clear. I am taking the example from Aron Rotteveel

```
$multi->setMultiOptions(array(
    'foo' => 'Foo',
    'bar' => 'Bar',
    'baz' => 'Baz',
    'bat' => 'Bat',
));
```

I want Foo and Bar to be selected while Baz and Bat should be unselected when the form is rendered. IE

```
<select name="categories[]" id="categories" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected" value="foo">foo</option>
    <option selected="selected"value="bar">bar</option>
    <option value="baz">baz</option>
    <option value="bat">bat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Am facing the same issue with zf2, can you please guide me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**You can pass an array of values to `setValue()`.**

The values in the array should correspond to the keys passed when setting the multiOptions.

```
$multi->setMultiOptions(array(
    'foo' => 'Foo',
    'bar' => 'Bar',
    'baz' => 'Baz',
    'bat' => 'Bat',
));

$multi->setValue(array('foo', 'bar'));
```

[From the ZF manual:](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiCheckbox)

> To mark checked items, you need to
>   pass an array of values to setValue().

Comment: Sorry, I do not know if my post is unclear or if you just misunderstood the post. But I want to set some of the options as selected. For example if we use your code. I want Foo and Bar to be selected, and Baz and Bat to unselected.

Comment: I see no mention of setValue() in the documentation. You've linked the multiCheckbox, but not the multiselect.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect

Answer (score 3):

I usually use setDefaults() on the form - you can also use setValue() on the element, but you set a multi-select's "selected options" as an array of selected id's (just like it returns for a value).

```
$categories = // model funciton to get selected categories for this entry.
$selected=array();
foreach ($categories as $category)
{
  $selected[] = $category->ID;
}
$form->setDefaults(array('categories' => $selected));
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but Arons answer is much more beautiful

Comment: I'm still wondering why the downvote... $form->setDefaults() is worth a mention - it will let you set multiple form values at a time as well.

Comment: I did not down vote you so I do not know. What is all this voting for anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to pass the options by array rather than using discrete elements, you can also do this:

```
$this->addElement('select', 'element_name', array(
  'label'=>'Element Label',
  'value'=> array('value_name'=>'Value Label',
  'multiOptions' => array(
      'value_name'=>'Value Label',
      'value_name_2'=>'Value Label 2',
      'value_name_3'=>'Value Label 3',
));
```

The important part is the 'value' key of the $options array.

This will cause the first element to be selected.